# How to paste graphics image data to folders in finder

Tags: finder, photos, shortcut, graphics, copy-paste

If you right click and copy an image from Safari, Mail, etc. (or command-control-shift-4 to save screenshot to clipboard), certain apps support pasting (e.g., Mail, MS Word, etc.), but I can't paste the image to a folder in finder.

Is there some way to override the default behavior, allowing me to paste to a folder, the aforementioned image data as a file using command-V? I don't really care what the file type is.

---

REVERTED EDITS TO QUESTION: See accepted answer to original question below.

Comment: The edit makes this a completely different question. Please consider posting it as such. The answers below now bear no relation to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to get something working (I asked a separate [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409212/detect-whether-clipboard-item-is-image-data-using-applescript) to extend this solution so that it will work with CMD-V instead of CTRL-CMD-V):

1. Install [pngpaste](https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) using `brew install pngpaste`.
2. Make Automator *Quick Action*, and configure as:

[image]

```
osascript -e 'set formattedDate to (do shell script "date +'%Y-%m-%dat%H-%M-%S%p'")' -e 'tell application "Finder" to set thePath to the quoted form of (POSIX path of (insertion location as alias) & formattedDate & ".png")' -e 'if ((clipboard info) as string) contains TIFF picture then do shell script "/usr/local/bin/pngpaste " & thePath' -e 'if ((clipboard info) as string) does not contain TIFF picture then tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using control down'
```

3. Save and close.
4. Assign a shortcut to trigger the service:

[image]

---

FUNCTIONALITY: If you want to paste any file just as normal, use CMD-V and if you want to paste a screenshot or image from the internet use CTRL-CMD-V.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can open Preview and use File → New from Clipboard (cmd-N). Preview opens the clipboard data and you can save this as a file to the location you desire.

Comment: See edits please.