# Detect whether clipboard item is image data using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator, copy-paste, image-capture

This started because [I wanted to be able to paste screenshots or pictures copied from Safari into Finder folders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409179/how-to-paste-graphics-image-data-to-folders-in-finder). Here are the steps to get to where I am:

1. Install [pngpaste](https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) using `brew install pngpaste`.
2. Make Automator *Quick Action*, and configure as:

[image]

```
osascript -e 'set formattedDate to (do shell script "date +'%Y-%m-%dat%H-%M-%S%p'")' -e 'tell application "Finder" to set thePath to the quoted form of (POSIX path of (insertion location as alias) & formattedDate & ".png")' -e 'if ((clipboard info) as string) contains TIFF picture then do shell script "/usr/local/bin/pngpaste " & thePath' -e 'if ((clipboard info) as string) does not contain TIFF picture then tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using control down'
```

3. Save and close.
4. Remap default paste:

[image]

5. Assign default paste to trigger service:

[image]

### THE ISSUE: No matter what type of file I have in my clipboard, the script always detects it as a TIFF and pastes it as a PNG. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just an FYI on your issue and presumably why your own workflow didn't produce the desired results… when I run 'clipboard info' on a PNG (from a screen shot) I get all manner of image types in the result — including TIFF. It's not actually detecting that it's a TIFF, it's just finding that string (along with GIF, BMP and JPEG and others). I think it's an issue of how the clipboard deals with binary data but not really sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having to write and maintain an `osascript` *command* as you have is really not the best way to go in this use case IMO.

Using a **Run AppleScript** *action*, instead of a **Run Shell Script** *action*, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will resolve the issue you are currently having, and makes the *code* much easier to read and edit:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set cbInfoAsString to (clipboard info) as string
    
    if cbInfoAsString does not contain "«class furl»" and ¬
        cbInfoAsString contains "TIFF picture" then
        
        set formattedDate to do shell script ¬
            "date -j '+%Y-%m-%d at %I.%M.%S %p'"
        
        tell application "Finder" to set thePath to ¬
            (insertion location as alias) & ¬
            formattedDate & ".png" as string
        
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/pngpaste " & ¬
            the quoted form of the POSIX path of thePath
        
    else if cbInfoAsString contains "«class furl»" then
        
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            keystroke "v" using control down
        
    end if
    
end run
```

**Notes:**

- `POSIX path` is a part of **Standard Additions** not **Finder**, and should not be wrapped within a `tell` *statement* of **Finder**.
- If not setting the *date* with the `date` *command*, use the `-j` *option*.
- I modified your `date` *command* to use **12-Hour Time** as typically **24-Hour Time** does not use **AM/PM** and have added made additional modifications to make it more readable, and in line with the system default used with screen shots.
- If you want  **24-Hour Time** then use e.g.: `"date -j '+%Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S'"`
- As coded, if there is anything other than a *file(s)/folder(s)* or just an *image*, the *script* will not attempt to process *text* if that's what's on the clipboard.

Comment: This works flawlessly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Landon, RE: "This works flawlessly." -- Considering your intended usage, i.e. the `insertion location` returned by **Finder** you have _read/write_ permissions, it should work without issue. However, as there is no _error handling_ included in the _code_ it can be problematic if the current `insertion location` is not _writable_, e.g. **Recents** or **Tags** is selected in **Finder**, or **Machintosh HD**. I just though it was worth mentioning.

Comment: A more direct approach that negates the need for ‘pngpaste` would be to `write (the clipboard as "PNGf") to f as "PNGf"` (after confirming `clipboard info for ”PNGf” ≠ {}`, and creating the file `close access (open for access f)` where `f` is the posix path to write out to).  Likewise, rather than key press a paste, one can either read the contents of the `furl` file object and write it out as before; or, use Finder or System Events to duplicate the file from the path stored in the `furl` object itself to the `insertion location`. _[ I realise these are the preserved parts of the OP’s code ]_

Comment: @CJK, The intent of my answer was to simply clean up the OP's existing coding and methodology as I didn't have time to delve into it any further at that point in time. The bottom line is, there usually is more than one way to do anything and there is almost always a better way to do the same thing. Take my answer compared to the other one in the other question you commented too just less than an hour ago at this point. :)

Comment: I guess it wasn’t as obvious as I thought it was, but the whole point of me adding _“I realise these are the preserved parts of the OP’s code”_ was so you wouldn’t have to justify yourself, as they are clearly additional notes primarily for the OP and/or anyone who cares. I understood what your answer was aiming to offer and where it was consciously putting a ceiling on how far outside the actual question it was intending to consider as extra credit. We both know you know your stuff and you know if it’s for you I’m more _“Why do it like that?!”_

Comment: Oh, if you were talking about the one I said I’ll edit, I am doing so.  I was just taking a break to skim through what I’ve missed for the past two months, having made my revisions twice, and lost them twice, because iPads are incredibly trying.

Comment: No that's not the one, the one on Shortcut to toggle KeyboardViewer with AppleScript on Big Sur

Comment: Update: Homebrew puts PNGpaste in a different directory by default now: `/usr/local/bin/pngpaste` → `/opt/homebrew/bin/pngpaste`