# How can I paste an SVG or PNG from clipboard as a file?

Tags: copy-paste

Figma allows to me [copy elements to clipboard as images](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409078832791-Copy-and-paste-objects-in-the-canvas#Copy_as_PNG): PNG or SVG. I can then paste these directly into some programs. For example, I can paste it as an image into Pages or Google Docs.

###### Problem

But many programs need an image to be a file before I can use it, usually by drag-and-drop.

###### What I've tried

Figma allows for exporting image files, but it's [a lot more steps](https://forum.figma.com/t/drag-and-drop-to-export-image/21159). I can also create a [new file from clipboard image](https://osxdaily.com/2011/06/29/quickly-create-a-new-image-file-from-clipboard-contents-with-preview/) with Preview, but that's again more steps, and it doesn't work for SVGs.

###### What I want

I'd like to be able to select my desktop or a folder, paste the image, and result in a new file. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Pasting an image into Pages is pasting the bytes, which gets translated to how the app uses the data in an open document. Finder is a fuel viewer, so it’s expecting you to paste an actual file information. It then operates on the file instead of the data.

Comment: I don't have Figma, but I generally find opening Preview.app and then creating a new document works.

Answer (score 3):

## Make an Automator service with a keyboard shortcut

1. Install PNG Paste
2. Paste code to make an Automator workflow
3. Add keyboard shortcuts to trigger the workflow

Using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in Finder.app will paste image data from the clipboard (if it's there) as a file, or else paste normally.

### 1. Install pngpaste

Run this [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) command in Terminal to install the [pngpaste](https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) command line utility.

1. `brew install pngpaste`

### 2. Make a Service with Automator

Make a type of Workflow called a *Service*, which will appear in *Finder menu → Finder → Services*. It tries to paste an image as a file, or else performs a normal paste.

2. Open Automator.app
3. New File → Quick Action → Choose
4. Set parameters

   > Filename: **Paste Clipboard Image as File**
   > Workflow receives **no input** in **Finder**
5. Add **Run AppleScript** action, and replace its code with

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set cbInfoAsString to (clipboard info) as string
    
    if cbInfoAsString contains "«class furl»" then
        
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            keystroke "v" using control down
        
    else
        set formattedDate to do shell script ¬
            "date -j '+%Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S'"
        
        if cbInfoAsString contains "TIFF picture" then  
            tell application "Finder" to set thePath to ¬
                (insertion location as alias) & ¬
                formattedDate & ".png" as string
            do shell script "/opt/homebrew/bin/pngpaste " & ¬
                the quoted form of the POSIX path of thePath
            
        else if paragraph 1 of (the clipboard as text) contains "<svg" then
            
            tell application "Finder" to set thePath to ¬
                (insertion location as alias) & ¬
                formattedDate & ".svg" as string
            do shell script "pbpaste -Prefer txt> " & ¬
                the quoted form of the POSIX path of thePath
            
        end if
    end if
end run
```

### 3. Add keyboard shortcuts

Remap Finder's normal Paste command to a secondary keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Then assign the primary keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to our new script.

6. System Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → App Shortcuts → Add (+)

   | Field | Value |
   | --- | --- |
   | Application | Finder.app |
   | Menu Title | Paste |
   | Keyboard Shortcut | <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> |
7. System Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Services → General

   Under *Paste Clipboard Image as File*, double-click `None` to replace it with keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

### 4. Test

8. Copy an image as image data. Use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste it into Finder. An image file should appear. Test for both PNG and SVG (e.g., in Figma's `Copy as PNG` and `Copy as SVG`).
9. Copy a non-image file. Use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste it into Finder. The file should appear like it would before you followed this guide.

If "Finder.app" wants access to "System Events.app", that's **OK**.

[image: "Finder.app" wants access to "System Events.app"]

Same for permitting the service to send keystrokes; give accessibility permissions to Finder.app to make this error go away.

[image: "Paste Clipboard Image as File is not allowed to send keystrokes."]

### Credit

The process has been adapted from [@Landon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/390906/landon). The code has been slightly modified from [@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894)'s answer to [Detect whether clipboard item is image data using AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409212/detect-whether-clipboard-item-is-image-data-using-applescript/409226#409226). This script does not have error-checking, so it may create unpredictable side effects when not used as prescribed.